# Java Alphabetizer

Tags: java, alphabetical

I'm trying to make a program in which I ask the user to input words, and then the program puts them in Alphabetical Order. Here's what I've got so far:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class WordAlphabeticalizer {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Variables and Objects
    String arraylength;
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    // Code
    System.out.println("Please input how many terms you would like to alphabetize"):                                                                    
    arraylength = input.nextLine();
    String[] words = new String[Integer.parseInt(arraylength)];

    for(int index = 0; index < words.length; index ++){
        System.out.println("Please input word number " + (index + 1) + ":");
        words[index] = input.nextLine();
        }
      }
    }
```

I would like to know how to go about comparing the first letters of each word in the array, and what logic I would use to keep going to compare the word to the first two, three, or how many ever spaces it needs to go in order to get which word goes first, and then the word that goes after it. Any ideas?

Comment: [`Arrays#sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object[]))

Comment: there are easier ways to do this.  Strings are Comparable.  You don't have to do all this to alphabetize.  Java is not C.

Comment: And if you *did* have a custom sort order (say, considering case or Unicode symbols differently than the default), you should look at using a java.util.Comparator<String> with Arrays.sort()

Answer (score 3):

[`java.lang.String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) implements the [`java.lang.Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface so you can sort them by adding them to a sorted collection (Try [`java.util.TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html))

```
Set<String> stringsToSort = new TreeSet<String>();
stringsToSort.add("Fish");
stringsToSort.add("Dog");
stringsToSort.add("Cat");

System.out.println(stringsToSort);
```

Comment: Note that this uses 'lexicographic' order, which is not _quite_ alphabetic order.  Specifically, capital letters are considered collectively 'less than' lower-case letters, since comparisons are performed by encoded value.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order

Comment: @KenoguLabz Good point.  `TreeSet` does have a constructor that takes a [`java.util.Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) so you could override the sort behavior to ignore case.

Comment: Although, if case doesn't matter, it would be significantly easier to just transform all input to lower/upper case.

Answer (score 0):

Though it's a bit verbose, this is a method I've used to alphabetise Strings:

```
public static String[] alphabetise(final String[] array)
{
    Arrays.sort(array, new Comparator<String>()
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(final String o1, final String o2)
        {
            if(o1 == null && o2 == null)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else if(o1 == null)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            else if(o2 == null)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else if(o1.equals(o2))
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else if(o1.isEmpty())
            {
                return -1;
            }
            else if(o2.isEmpty())
            {
                return 1;
            }
            final Character[] c1 = toCharacterArray(o1.toLowerCase());
            final Character[] c2 = toCharacterArray(o2.toLowerCase());
            final int max = Math.max(c1.length, c2.length);
            for(int i = 0; i < max; i++)
            {
                if(i < c1.length && i < c2.length)
                {
                    final int comp = c1[i].compareTo(c2[i]);
                    if(comp != 0)
                    {
                        return comp;
                    }
                }
                else return new Integer(c1.length).compareTo(new Integer(c2.length));

            }
            return 0;
        }
    });
    return array;
}

static Character[] toCharacterArray(final String str)
{
    if(str == null || str.isEmpty()) return new Character[0];
    final Character[] array = new Character[str.length()];
    int counter = 0;
    for(final char c : str.toCharArray())
    {
        array[counter++] = c;
    }
    return array;
}
```

This will conform to proper alphabetical order, ignoring capitals and favouring shorter words over longer (e.g. "House" before "Houses").